# What is the Pandas equivalent for matlab code A(A(:,4)==0,:)=[];?

Tags: python, pandas, data-preprocessing

The code `A(A(:,4)==0,:)=[];` in MATLAB drops rows in matrix A if values in the fourth column are zero.

I tried to write a code of `A=A[A[:,4] !==0]`, given that pandas is called but it was rejected in python.

If the code runs well in python, I expect that it will be ignoring rows where the values in the fourth column are zeros. The original data will not be affected in excel.

Comment: something like `A=A.loc[A.iloc[:, 4] != 0]`

Comment: `!==` - Is that a typo of `!=`?

Comment: FWIW, if your data is like a matrix (i.e. unlabeled and all the same dtype), you might want to use NumPy instead since indexing by position is more straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to select the column and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
A = A[A.iloc[:, 4] != 0]
```

Variants:

```
A = A[A.iloc[:, 4].ne(0)]

A = A.loc[A.iloc[:, 4] != 0]

# only if the column name is unique
A = A[A[A.columns[4]] != 0]
```